# Napoleon's role in serfdom abolition

Tags: napoleon

It is known that Napoleon has given constitutions to a set of countries.
The constitutions were written in the style of the French one.

How many of those napoleonic constitutions have played a role in serfdom abolition?

I know that serfdom has been cancelled at least in [Duchy if Warsaw](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constitution_of_the_Duchy_of_Warsaw) and [Westphalia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kingdom_of_Westphalia), but surely there are more to it. On the other hand, some places could have already gotten rid of serfdom in advance. And some could restore it right after Napoleon's fall.

Comment: An interesting related question is that how many countries did not revert this serfdom/feudalism reform after 1815

Answer (score 1):

Whenever Napoleon conquered land the [Napoleonic Code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Napoleonic_Code) followed. The Napoleonic Code abolished all feudalism, therefor [serfdom](https://simple.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serfdom) was no longer needed because it was the lowest social class in the feudal society.

Comment: Not always, the code enshrined property rights, and feudal rights were often translated into property rights. Serfdom was retained in someplace especially on the estates allocated to Napoloen's new nobility,